# 500 error from apache + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

I'm trying to use setup the rails application on apache2 using the virtual server method, which is where I think my problems are coming from.  I tried the standalone passenger install (after spending yesterday afternoon trying to make apache work) and that worked just fine, but I'd like to use apache.

Apache error log shows:

```
[Thu Jan 26 22:36:18 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Jan 26 22:36:20 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
cache: [GET /videos] miss
```

The sigterm is me restarting apache.  The cache miss is me trying to view the model's page.

The virtual host setup

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/dave/prodspace/river/public
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/dave/prodspace/river/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

The folder that contains everything is /home/dave/prodspace/river, I have set group permissions to www-data for the river/public folder.  I have enabled the site and restarted apache via 
sudo a2ensite river
sudo service apache2 restart

System specs are:
ruby related things installed using rvm
ruby 1.9.2p290
passenger 3.0.11
rails 3.2.0
apache 2.2 (installed through apt-get packages)
ubuntu 11.10 (x86 server edition)

Any help is always appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The production database wasn't set up.  The fix ended up being running:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create db:schema:load
```

Answer (score 1):

I have to deal with this regularly at my work. A few things that come into play here are as follows: (NOTE: I use RVM for my dev at work also)

- cd into your app directory for the project
- Make sure that you have installed the passenger gem (gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc passenger
- Then make surer to run the passenger apache module install (rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module)
- Then you want to be sure to enable the apache mods in your /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

  - You'll want the passenger.load & passenger.conf both enabled in your apache config.

Now, it should be noted that passenger doesn't play nice unless you perform an added little bit here as referenced [here](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/).

Create a new file in your config/ directory called setup_load_path.rb and paste this in there:

```
if ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'] && ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME'].include?('rvm')
  begin
    rvm_path     = File.dirname(File.dirname(ENV['MY_RUBY_HOME']))
    rvm_lib_path = File.join(rvm_path, 'lib')
    $LOAD_PATH.unshift rvm_lib_path
    require 'rvm'
    RVM.use_from_path! File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
  rescue LoadError
    # RVM is unavailable at this point.
    raise "RVM ruby lib is currently unavailable."
  end
end
```

Now restart your apache and it should be working if your routing is setup properly.

Comment: Also, if you want your application to run in dev mode for debugging purposes, add this to your <Virtualhost> body. RailsEnv development

Comment: I didn't see a line that had passenger.load or passenger.conf in apache2.conf, and passenger was not in the list of mods-enabled or mods-available.  

I do have passenger 3.0.11 installed, and I have run passenger-install-apache-module and copied the three lines and appended them to apache2.conf.

Comment: If you copied the lines into the apache2.conf, then you don't need to worry about the mods-enabled stuff. The critical aspect of this is that setup_load_path.rb file. This is because passenger attempts to use your system ruby & rails instead of the gemset you have installed. Can you paste the output of 'gem list', please?

Comment: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.0)
actionpack (3.2.0, 3.2.0.rc2)
activemodel (3.2.0, 3.2.0.rc2)
activerecord (3.2.0)
activeresource (3.2.0)
activesupport (3.2.0, 3.2.0.rc2)
arel (3.0.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.0.21)
coffee-rails (3.2.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.0)
jquery-rails (2.0.0)
json (1.6.5)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86-linux)
mail (2.4.1)
mime-types (1.17.2)
multi_json (1.0.4)
passenger (3.0.11)

Comment: polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.0)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.0)
railties (3.2.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
sass (3.1.12)
sass-rails (3.2.3)
sprockets (2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
therubyracer (0.9.9)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
uglifier (1.2.2)

Comment: Aside from the 500 Error mentioned in your title here, are you getting a Passenger error page? What happens when you attempt to pull up your application in the browser?

Comment: I was getting an error page from missing gems(the coffees and sprockets, I think), but when I installed them the page that came up was the http error 500 page from the app.  I haven't changed the routing at all; when I go straight to the IP address I get the standard "getting started" page, but when I try to go to <insert IP address>/videos I get the 500 error page.

Comment: Are you able to run the app in dev mode using to script/server and navigating to localhost:3000/videos? If that works but the passenger implementation isn't, then something is most certainly wrong with the passenger installation and may need to be uninstalled and reinstalled/configured.

Comment: I've been running `rails server` and then visiting localhost:3000/videos which performs exactly as it should on my dev machine.

Comment: I'm leaning more & more toward something not being good with the passenger install. I'm also running out of troubleshooting options. If I were encountering this, I would try to uninstall the passenger gem and reinstall it. Obviously, you do not want to install any gems in RVM as root. I only do root level stuff for system-wide ruby install.

Comment: Some more googling has led me to this:  http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/07faa65a13b73a5c
Starting webrick in production mode `rails s -e production` and visiting the page in my web browser causes the same error on the console that apache produced.